# How can I use gcc to compile C program whose name does not end with ".c"?

Tags: gcc

Compiling C program using gcc is very simple. Just such a command:

```
gcc code.c -o executable
```

However, if the code file name does not end with ".c", gcc will treat it as a linker script. How can I use gcc to compile C program whose name does not end with ".c"?

Comment: Rename the file with a .c

Answer (score 3):

With GCC, the `-x` switch specifies the language to compile for:

```
gcc -x c code.foo -o executable
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `-x` switch to specify the language.

```
gcc -xc -o executable anything
```

You can even read from stdin:

```
echo 'int main() { printf("Hello world"); }' | gcc -xc -o executable -
```